# Firebase Functions - How To Verify Loading Static Content From CDN Cache?

Tags: javascript, firebase, caching, google-cloud-functions, server-side-rendering

I am building a server-side rendered react, redux application. I am returning http requests with an express app on Firebase Cloud Functions.

I have caching enabled with this line:

```
res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=1200, s-maxage=1200');
```

How do I verify that when I clear my browser cache and hit reload, that it's loading from the CDN cache, and not running the function all over again? How do I know it is working?

Does the local cli work in the same way that I should expect the fully deployed version to work?

```
firebase serve --only functions,hosting
```

**Server-Side index.js file**

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
// import { StaticRouter } from "react-router";
import express from "express";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

// Import Components, Reducers, Styles
//import App from "../shared/components/App";
import News from "../shared/containers/News";
import reducers from "../shared/reducers";

// Prepare our store to be enhanced with middleware
const middleware = [thunk];
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(...middleware)(createStore);

// Create store, compatible with REDUX_DEVTOOLS (chrome extension)
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers);

const app = express();
app.get('**', (req, res) => {
  const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <News />
    </Provider>
  );
  const preloadedState = store.getState();
  res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=1200, s-maxage=1200');
  res.send(renderFullPage(html, preloadedState));
});

function renderFullPage(html, preloadedState) {
  return `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>React Server Side Rendering - Firebase Hosting</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="root">${html}</div>
        <script>
          window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(preloadedState).replace(/</g, '\\u003c')}
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
  `
}

export let ssrapp = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Answer (score 1):

Even when loading the URL triggers Cloud Functions, the file will always be served from the CDN. So while you can check for headers (`via` and `x-served-by` in case you're curious) whether it indeed comes from an edge cache (and which one), you can't from the response you get see if it triggered Cloud Functions.

The best option I can think of is to check in the Cloud Functions logs, to see if the function was run.